# Android view doesn't accept clicks

Tags: android

I add a listview via Java into @+id/View01.
For some reason the items in the listview don't accept clicks.
Does anybody have ideas about possible causes?

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/light_blue"
  >
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
        android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
    <AbsoluteLayout 
    android:id="@+id/Layout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button01"        
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <View android:id="@+id/View01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
        <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView02" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button02" 
        android:id="@+id/Button02" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I change my code to the following the clicks work but the layout doesn't look the way I want.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/light_blue"
  >
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" 
        android:id="@+id/Button01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <View android:id="@+id/View01" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button01"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView02" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/View01"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button02"/>
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button02" 
        android:id="@+id/Button02" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

One of the functions involved:

```
protected void initiateExtraView(FillInput fillInput){
    View extraView = fillInput.getExtraView();
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) extraView.getParent();
    int index = parent.indexOfChild(extraView);
    parent.removeView(extraView);
    extraView = fillInput.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
             R.layout.extrabuttonlistview, 
             parent, 
             false);

    parent.addView(extraView, index);
    fillInput.setExtraView(extraView);

    ListView extraButtonView = (ListView) extraView;
    fillInput.setExtraButtonListView(extraButtonView);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ExtraButtonAdapter(fillInput, this);
    fillInput.getExtraButtonListView().setAdapter(adapter);     
}
```

The function in the ExtraButtonAdapter that create the particular view that doesn't accept clicks:

```
private View getNewForm(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.new_form_button, 
            parent, 
            false);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Click on NewForm");
        }
    };
    view.setOnClickListener(listener);

    setNewFormView(view);
    return view;
}
```

R.layout.extrabuttonlistview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button02"/>
```

Comment: Have you set `ListView.setOnItemClickListener` ?

Comment: How do you know it does not accept clicks? Can you post your code? Do you set click listener?

Comment: My code is pretty complex with doesn't allow posting everything. I have set an OnClickListener for the view.

Comment: You don't have to post your whole project here, just a little excerpt where you set the listener and probably the code of the listener itself. It's very unlikely that 5-20 lines of code could be so secure that someone could steal your idea or make an app of his own. Without code example it's just much harder to say what's wrong with yours code

Comment: The total code that gets called is a lot longer than 5-20 lines. I can post the 20 lines of one function.

Answer (score 0):

By default ListView does not pass touch events through to a child unless it can accept focus. You can change this behavior by calling `setItemsCanFocus(true)`.

The default behavior of ListView treats items as single units and dispatches click events using an `OnItemClickListener` attached to the ListView itself.

Comment: Calling setItemsCanFocus(true) doesn't change anything. It would also not explain why the second code works when the first doesn't. When I add an OnItemClickListener to the ListView it also doesn't receive any clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried to replace the `<View android:id="@+id/View01"` with a

```
<ViewStub android:id="@+id/listViewStub" android:inflateId="@+id/View01" android:layout="@layout/layout/new_form_button" />
```

and in code you could inflate it by

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub)findViewById(R.id.listViewStub);
stub.inflate();
```

Seems weird that you try to add a ListView into a View element.

Advantage of inflating with ViewStub is, that once inflated the "ViewStub" Element will be completely replaced by your ListView and then be equal to your ListView02 and will reduce your Hierarchy depth by one.

[ViewStub Documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html)

**edit:** 
Maybe [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) is more suitable then.

Comment: I want to be able to put different stuff into the View on runtime. As far as I can see a ViewStub can't change it's content after it has been inflated.

Comment: Maybe try `ViewGroup` instead. The view class kinda seems to be the wrong class to add other views to it.